# Receiving a notification on a Cluster Group Failover

Tags: monitoring, failover, windows-cluster

I have several Windows Cluster set up and I have the need of keeping track of failovers. I'd need to receive a notification of sort whenever a group fails over. I've seen some examples around, but I can't rely on the approach of just sending a message whenever the resources are stopped/restarted as it would generate too many false alarms. In few words, I need to be notified if and only if the group really fails over.

I was thinking that probably the best way is monitoring the System Event Log, but, if possible, I'd prefer not having to write a script/program from scratch for this issue. Is there any script/product that already does it? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @Chopper3 said, SCOM can do this (and a whole lot more).

If you're running Server 2008, you can attach a task to an event via built in options, so you could attach for example an email task to the failover event in the log.

Comment: Thanks. At the end, the whole thing has been abandoned. Management decided that SCOM won't be used, as the SysAdmins (which I'm not) don't know it; they suggested that I'd implement something similar from scratch, as "it would be cheaper", but I convinced them otherwise.

Answer (score 1):

[SCOM](http://www.microsoft.com/systemcenter/en/us/operations-manager.aspx) can do this for you.

Answer (score 0):

Is there a Win performance counter available from the failover operation?  If it's an MS solution there should be several perf counters that give you details.  If not, you can create one or mare as needed.  Perf counters can be readily extracted, displayed, graphed historically, and events can be created based on the values in the perf counters.  The event results in email &/or SMS.  Best if it's tied to something that will help you get to root cause as well.